# How to get the children width from a htmlelement (elementref)

Tags: html, angular, children, elementref

I need to get the width of all children from a elementref.

The items are dynamically loaded

Typescript:

```
@ViewChild('mainSubMenu') subMenu: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const greedyNav = this.subMenu.nativeElement;
    let totalSpace = 0;
    let breakWidths = [];
    let itemCount = 0;

   // Loop over all elements and set sum of widths for each menu item
   for (const i of greedyNav.children) {
     totalSpace += greedyNav.children[i].clientWidth;
     breakWidths.push(totalSpace);
     itemCount += 1;
     }
   }
```

html:

```
   <nav class="sub-nav-tabs">
    <ul class="main-sub-menu" #mainSubMenu>
      <li class="sub-menu-item" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuitems">
        <a class="sub-menu-link">{{menuItem.item}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Change this: `const greedyNav = this.mainSubMenu.nativeElement;` to `const greedyNav = this.subMenu.nativeElement;`

Comment: from my experience, usually when someone asks how to read the width of an element it implies hes trying to solve a CSS issue with javascript. are you familiar with the `flexbox` property ?

Comment: @xyz indeed. copy paste mistake for this question

Comment: @stavm. yes indeed. I know what I can do with flexbox. I need to calculate the width of the menu items so I can put some items in a seperate menu when there is not enough space available.

Comment: @Babulaas Doesn't the answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method like:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const greedyNav = this.subMenu.nativeElement;
    let totalSpace = 0;
    let breakWidths = [];
    let itemCount = 0;

  // Loop over all elements and set sum of widths for each menu item
  for (const eachChild of greedyNav.children) {
    totalSpace += eachChild.clientWidth;
    breakWidths.push(totalSpace);
    itemCount += 1;
    }
  }
```

You are looping your array using `of` operator so you get eachChild itself in the loop, not the index.